# Vue Bootstrap slider. How detect @mouseup

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i've using vue-bootstrap slider, which has 2 actions (@change, @update)

I want to catch final position of slider, when move ends, so i decided to test both.

@change should work only when scroll is done, but in my case works when i'm moving scroll even before i make mouse up, @update doesn't work at all.

Is there any possibility to use any action, which will be activated when i will scroll and mouse up?

My code is:

```
<vue-slider style="position: absolute; margin-left: 1285px;"
          v-model="value"
          direction="ttb"
          :height="800"
          class="mr-1 vue-slider-warning"
          :tooltip="'none'"
          @change="scrollMeNew"
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this component but you can give @mouseup parent element of slider. Like that;

```
  <div @mouseup="triggered">
    <VSlickCarousel class="slickCarousel" v-bind="carouselSettings">
      <div class="big-carousel-item">
        <img
          width="1064"
          height="320"
          src="/images/leaugeoflegends.jpg"
          alt=""
          @click.stop
        />
      </div>
```